# What is the fastest way to properly rig and animate organics?

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

What is the easiest and fastest way to properly rig organic objects?

I have a organically-formed turret (shown below) which will need to tilt 90 degrees up, all the way to 45 degrees down.

I was assuming to a) have a trail of bones (not sure how many) from the center of the base, leading/curving up to the shooting point of the weapon, b) to set parent with automatic weights, and c) rig each vine individually.

I was also thinking that "proportional bone editing" or something of the sort will help keep the organic flow of the turret during animation?

Any help greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could parent it to a curve or something, and then use the curve to deform the mesh?